# Cashier Braintree plan-credit discount needed for prorateing subscriptions

Tags: laravel, braintree

Laravels documentation mentiones that if I want to use Cashier with Braintree that I need to create  plan-credit discount inside Braintree, and that this discount is used for changin from yearly to montly and montly to yearly. Do I need to create this discount if I only want to offer montly subscriptions?

Laravels documentation on Cashier Braintree:

> Before using Cashier with Braintree, you will need to define a plan-credit discount in your Braintree control panel. This discount will be used to properly prorate subscriptions that change from yearly to monthly billing, or from monthly to yearly billing.
>
> The discount amount configured in the Braintree control panel can be any value you wish, as Cashier will simply override the defined amount with our own custom amount each time we apply the coupon. This coupon is needed since Braintree does not natively support prorating subscriptions across subscription frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is just for swapping across billing frequencies of same plan